# How VS.NET detects that extension should be updated?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

from time to time a dialog pops up in VS.NET telling me that there's new version of an installed extension. I know that the extensions are officially stored on this [location](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/), but what if someone does not want to expose the extension he made to public? I mean it is for example a company top-secret extension that only the employees can use.

The question is are the updates detected by VS.NET or the extensions can check for their updates individually. If so, then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using Visual Studio 2012 or later, under Tools > Options, General, Extension and Updates, you can register a private gallery. All you have to do is drop an XML file somewhere on a web server that contains some version info of the latest versions of your extensions, and VS will poll that to check. The XML file is an Atom feed and the format is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266717.aspx).